# Mac keyboard shortcuts during Zoom remote access from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, zoom-meeting

I'm connecting from Ubuntu to Mac via Zoom and I need to use keyboard shortcuts like copy/paste (and many more).

How do I invoke <kbd>Command</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>) <kbd>⌘</kbd>?
My keyboard has the <kbd>Windows</kbd> <kbd>⊞</kbd> key but it doesn't seem to work as <kbd>Command</kbd>. Could be an issue on my Ubuntu though.

Comment: Try Ctrl instead - some systems are smart enough to translate [some aren't].

Comment: @Tetsujin - nope, it didn't work. I suspect Ctrl is sent as Control which is a different key on Mac. I tried combinations like CTRL+ALT, CTRL+SHIFT... you name it.

Comment: If you like puzzles, it would be interesting to see what the Mac thinks is being sent. You can get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store; in the meantime, the Mac should let you right click or ctrl/click to get a contextual menu for copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally using [Key Codes](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915) recommended by @Tetsujin I was able to compile the list below. Both my local Ubuntu and remote Mac use Czech layout.

I was hoping to produce <kbd>Command</kbd> so that I can use it to type symbols. I discovered that for that, I needed <kbd>Option</kbd>.

Basically, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> on Ubuntu works as <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Mac. So to strip off the Ctrl part, I need to press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly touch and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and after that <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> works only as <kbd>Option</kbd>.

| desired symbol | how to produce |
| --- | --- |
| $ | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> (actually `č` on Czech keyboard) |
|  | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> (<kbd>ů</kbd>) appears to produce the same key code as `$` in `Key Codes` however, doesn't produce `$` in PhpStorm |
| # | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> (`š`) |
| [ | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (1. key after P) |
| ] | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> (2. key after P) |
| \ | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd> (3. key after P) |
| | | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (3. key after P) |
| < | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd> (1. key after M) |
| > | <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, briefly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd> (2. key after M) |
| ( ) = - _ | no surprises here, use what you'd press locally |

| action | how to produce |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Command</kbd> | <kbd>Right Win</kbd> (Left Win triggers local response, Zoom doesn't send it across) |
| cut | <kbd>Right Win</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> |
| copy | <kbd>Right Win</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> |
| paste | I haven't found a solution (<kbd>Right Win</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> doesn't work) |
| jump by words | <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> |
| beginning / end of a row | no surprises (<kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>) |

I hope someone will find a way to trigger `paste` :)